# Undo the pushed changes by designer on bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

I am still getting used to bitbucket and TortoiseHg. 
I pushed my changes two days ago to bitbucket. Then the designer pulled those changes and he had some changes and commited and pushed today. I am not sure what happened but his changes has messed up lot many things. I have not pulled his changes yet on my machine.

Is there a way to remove his changeset from bitbuket as if it was never pushed.

Or what is the best way to go about in this case.

This might be very simple. I am still looking around the web and docs but hope someone can here can help.

Comment: Make sure you talk to your designer in order to figure out what "went wrong" from your perspective, otherwise he might be upset you just decided his changes were no good, and unless you communicate, you risk him/her doing the same thing again.

Comment: @Lasse: Thanks. Fortunately, it came down to a minor glitch in one file only and he was able to fix it. So nothing lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `hg backout` to undo the bad changeset he pushed. See the Mercurial book on [Finding and fixing mistakes](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html).

Comment: I am reading that and not able to understand exactly. After running the backout, will the designer have to do any commit and push again to bitbucket? If so what will he lose his changes upon backout and what happens when I do a pull? It's kind of confusing to me.

Comment: Yes backout will generate a new commit and that will have to be pushed just like any other commit. If all the work was done it one commit it will all be reversed by the backout. If there were multiple commits and you can identify where the problem was introduced then only that commit(s) needs to be backedout. When you do a pull you will get the set of changes which exist on the remote but not in your local repo. You will then have to update/merge your work in with the designer's work.

Comment: Thanks. I will follow the instructions and see how it goes.

Comment: Although didn't have to use this but was really helpful.